# ffmpeg merge video and audio + fade out

Tags: ffmpeg

I have one video file and one audio file.
I want to merge them together that the final output video will be in the length of the video and will contain the audio in the background.

i did:

```
ffmpeg -i output.avi -i bgmusic.mp3 -filter_complex " [1:0] apad " -shortest out.avi
```

but the background audio is cut in the end of the final merge movie.
i want it to fade out nicely.

how can i do it??

but the background audio is cut in the end of the final merge movie.
i want it to fade out nicely.

how can i do it??

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use --ss and -t option to add audio to the output file:
-ss [...] will define the starting point to cut 
-t [...] will define the length of the segment in seconds 
exemple:

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:10  -t 5 -i "video.mp4" -ss 0:00:01 -t 5 -i "music.m4a" -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0 -y out.mp4
```

Then you can use the afade effect to the last duration:
afade options :

type, t
Specify the effect type, can be either in for fade-in, or out for a fade-out effect. Default is in.

start_sample, ss
Specify the number of the start sample for starting to apply the fade effect. Default is 0.

duration, d
Specify the duration of the fade effect. See (ffmpeg-utils)the Time duration section in the ffmpeg-utils(1) manual for the accepted syntax. At the end of the fade-in effect the output audio will have the same volume as the input audio, at the end of the fade-out transition the output audio will be silence. By default the duration is determined by nb_samples. If set this option is used instead of nb_samples.

**exemple** :

```
afade=t=in:ss=0:d=15
```